# Nontrivial examples of locally compact quantum groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, quantum-groups

What are some families of locally compact quantum groups that are neither groups, duals of groups, compact, nor discrete?

Comment: There should be some examples in Timmerman. I think Sołtan might have been involved in some of them. I am not 100% sure if they are not discrete though.

Comment: Also see recent paper by Rollier and  Vaes on quantum automorphism groups of a class of graphs.

Comment: Quantum versions of non-compact Lie groups, e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.05661

Comment: Therr are various constructions to build lcqg's from old ones. For example, if you tensor a non-trivial compact and discrete quantum group, you get something that is genuinely locally compact. The Drinfeld double construction of a non-trivial compact/discrete quantum group also produces a genuine locally compact quantum group.